# MongooseError: Operation `users.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms on webpage error

Tags: node.js, authentication, mongoose

when I try to click on login button I get this error on my webpage :-

```
MongooseError: Operation `users.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
```

my post login js code is:-

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    res.render('login', {
        user: req.user
    });
});

app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
        if (err) return next(err)
        if (!user) {
            return res.redirect('/login')
        }
        req.logIn(user, function(err) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        return res.redirect('/');
    });
});
```

Any suggestions why I am getting this error are appreciated

Comment: It looks as if you're trying to fetch data from mongoDB without actually connecting to the database first. Read [this article](https://www.tutorialkart.com/nodejs/mongoose/connect-to-mongodb/) for information on how to get started.

Comment: yeah, got it, after making the connection it works fine